# Maintaining user log in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am a beginner java learner.. Currently i am working on jsp.

I am making a user-log for all the activities of the user in my database. I've included the 'timestamp' using the `current_timestamp` function, then the page visited by the user, and then the user-agent using the `request.getHeader("User-Agent")` function.

Shall i also include the session-id in the log?

Is it of any significance while auditing or for any other purpose?

My jsp project is a simple log in log out webapp with a database with the user details at the back end.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you can save sessionid,login_user_name,user_agent,timestamp,remote_ip and so on.

Comment: So how should they do it then?

Comment: create a table in the database with all these variable. Get the sessionid by session.getId().. username might have been stored in session, it is in mine so you can get it from there by session.getAttribute("username"), useragent by request.getHeader("User-Agent"), timestamp by current_timestamp and ip by request.getRemoteAddr(). Then an insert query.. insert into table_name values(login_user_name,user_agent,timestamp,remote_ip)

Comment: I am also trying to save the url visited by the user. by using request.getRequestUri(). But at times my url looks something like this: prac2/view-details.jsp?u=user124
By using this method i cannot get the part u=user124.. Is there any way in jsp that i can store this in my log as well?